# Не работает скрипт для фиксированного меню

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всё подключил, всё проверил, скрипт всё равно не работает.

```
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Сам скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > $('header').height() + 20)
        $('nav').addClass('fixed');
    else
        $('nav').removeClass('fixed');
});
```

Стили:

```
#nav.fixed {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0.97;
 }
```

В чём проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы забыли тут `#` (если `nav` - это `id`, судя по стилям):

```
$('#nav').addClass('fixed');
$('#nav').removeClass('fixed');
```

Попробуйте также 
`$(window).scrollTop()` вместо `$(document).scrollTop()`

Также нужно поместить это в обработчик события Scroll:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('header').height() + 20)
       $('#nav').addClass('fixed');
    else
       $('#nav').removeClass('fixed');
})
```

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(window).scroll(function() {
     if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('header').height() + 20)
       $('#nav').addClass('fixed');
     else
       $('#nav').removeClass('fixed');
   })
 });
```

```css
#nav {
  color: #999;
  height: 50px;
}
body {
  height: 2000px
}
#nav.fixed {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="nav">
  NAV
</header>
```

Comment: Исправил, все равно не работает

Comment: Попробуйте `$(window).scrollTop()` вместо `$(document).scrollTop()`

Comment: Опять-таки. Может не в коде проблема. Ибо вот ссылка демонстрации фиксированного меню https://artinblog.ru/uploads/posts/demo/jQuery/fiksirovannoje-menu.html
И у меня и тут не работает скрипт

Comment: Обновил ответ, посмотрите.

Comment: @антон на указанном сайте в скрипте есть строка `$(window).scroll(function() {`, которая добавляет (вместе с остальным кодом) обработчик события скролла страницы. Поэтому функция внутри на сайте вызывается при каждом скролле. У вас же, в приведённом в вопросе коде, всё исполняется только один раз, при загрузке странице. Будьте внимательнее.

Comment: Нет, опять ничего

Comment: @антон и добавьте в вопрос соответствующий HTML-код, чтобы не приходилось гадать.

Comment: так-так-так. все заработало. всем спасибо :)

Comment: @антон тогда не забудьте отметить ответ как верный.